# shiny-server Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: r, internal, rcharts, shiny-server

I'm using shiny-server on centos 6, it works well with most of my apps, but there is something wrong
when I use it with rCharts(ggplot2 is ok).  The chrome gives me a message that " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) ",but I can run the same code on my local Windows7 system。 and there is no error log about it. what's wrong with it.
if any friend know how to deal with it please tell me , thanks.

the code is :

## server.R

```
require(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
    p1 <- rPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, color = "Species", 
      facet = "Species", type = 'point')
    p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    return(p1)
  })
})

#ui.R
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R using polychart.js"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
     label = "Choose X",
     choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
     selected = "SepalLength"),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
      label = "Choose Y",
      choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
      selected = "SepalWidth")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "polycharts")
  )
))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yeah！ I have finally check it  out that because I have not change the mode of the app (ui.R and server.R)
to the mode readable! after chmod 755 of ui.R and server.R, It worked well.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue.  What is the readable mode? Thnaks

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.